# Python Sentry integration only for some modules

Tags: python, sentry

absolute Sentry beginner here, and junior developer, so sorry in advance if my questions are dumb.

My use case is that I'm making two python packages, foo and bar, one (bar) using the other (foo). My issue is that I want Sentry to only receive errors from foo, not from bar.

So let's assume this simple example:

```
foo/
    foo/
        __init__.py
            import sentry_sdk  
              
            sentry_sdk.init(  
                dsn="blablabla",
                traces_sample_rate=1.0, 
                in_app_include=["foo"]
            )
            
        main.py
            def test():  
                raise ValueError("Foo error")  # I want this to be caugh by Sentry
                
bar/
    bar/
        __init__.py
        
        main.py:
            import foo.main  

            raise ValueError("Bar error")  # I dont want this to be caught by Sentry
            foo.main.test()
```

Am I misunderstanding how Sentry works, of what it is for?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you import foo you initialize sentry, sentry does not operate in packages, it overrides python packages globally. Just don't initialize sentry on import

Comment: Not sure to understand, how to I monitor a whole package, without having parasite noise from the packages that use the package I'm monitoring then?